# Prediction with ANN are most of the time false

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist, digits

my probleme is that my ANN predicts only about 2 times out of 10 the right digit but when the ANN was fitted it tells me about 98% accuarcy. I'm quit a starter with ANNS and I don't know if I'm missing something abvious or why it is like it is.
For testing I use a tabel with 81 digits (allways in a row from 1 to 9).
I would be grateful if someone can help me :)

Training the ANN

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras.models import save_model

# See available datasets
print(tfds.list_builders())

# Construct a tf.data.Dataset
dataset = tfds.load(name="mnist", split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)

# Build your input pipeline
dataset = dataset.shuffle(1024).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
for features in dataset.take(1):
  image, label = features["image"], features["label"]

# tfds works in both Eager and Graph modes


# See available datasets
print(tfds.list_builders())

# Construct a tf.data.Dataset
dataset = tfds.load(name="mnist", split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)

# Build your input pipeline
dataset = dataset.shuffle(1024).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
for features in dataset.take(1):
  image, label = features["image"], features["label"]

  mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

# Aufteilung in Training- und Testset
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
print(x_test[0])
# TF Bilderkennungsmodell
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

# Crossentropy für die 10 Zahlen Klassen
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Modellfitting und Evaluation
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

filepath = './saved_model2'
save_model(model, filepath)
```

For testing with my table:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import cv2
import PIL


# Model configuration
img_width, img_height = 28, 28
batch_size = 250
no_epochs = 25
no_classes = 10
validation_split = 0.2
verbosity = 1


filepath = './saved_model2'

model = load_model(filepath, compile=True)
img = PIL.Image.open("Dataset/raster.jpg")
bilder = []

i= 0
for x in range(0,224,28):
    img1 = img.crop([0,x,28,x+28])
    img2 = img.crop([28,x,56,x+28])
    img3 = img.crop([56,x,84,x+28])
    img4 = img.crop([84,x,112,x+28])
    img5 = img.crop([112,x,140,x+28])
    img6 = img.crop([140,x,168,x+28])
    img7 = img.crop([168,x,196,x+28])
    img8 = img.crop([196,x,224,x+28])
    img9 = img.crop([224,x,252,x+28])
    img1.save("Dataset/eigeneBilder/"+str(i+1)+".jpg")
    img2.save("Dataset/eigeneBilder/"+str(i+2)+".jpg")
    img3.save("Dataset/eigeneBilder/"+str(i+3)+".jpg")
    img4.save("Dataset/eigeneBilder/"+str(i+4)+".jpg")
    img5.save("Dataset/eigeneBilder/"+str(i+5)+".jpg")
    img6.save("Dataset/eigeneBilder/"+str(i+6)+".jpg")
    img7.save("Dataset/eigeneBilder/"+str(i+7)+".jpg")
    img8.save("Dataset/eigeneBilder/"+str(i+8)+".jpg")
    img9.save("Dataset/eigeneBilder/"+str(i+9)+".jpg")
    i += 9
print(bilder)

samples_to_predict = []
for i in range(1,81,1):
    # Generate a plot
    sample = cv2.imread("Dataset/eigeneBilder/"+str(i)+".jpg")
    img = cv2.bitwise_not(sample)
    sample = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    reshaped_image = sample.reshape((img_width, img_height,1))
    plt.imshow(reshaped_image)
    reshaped_image/255
    # Add sample to array for prediction
    samples_to_predict.append(reshaped_image)

samples_to_predict = np.array(samples_to_predict)

print(samples_to_predict[0])
predictions = model.predict(samples_to_predict)
classes = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
print(samples_to_predict)
print(classes)
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is add validation_data in model.fit like this :

```
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_data=(x_test,y_test))
```

You can also add some 2Dconv layers with pooling before the flatten one. Or add more neurones.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Now there are different numbers but it isn't much better. But I won't stop trying until I found the probleme then I will tell you :D

Comment: Okay, if I find something as well I will tell you, I am also new ;).

Comment: I think I got it now. A big problem was in the prediction the list befor the actual prediction. Because now it is making one prediction after another and it is doing it now much better. I'm also playing with the amount of layers and at my last test it predicted every digit except the 3 and the 8 right.

Comment: Nice great news ! What do you mean by list before prediction ?